# C# MySQL command timeout

Tags: c#, mysql, timeout

I have specified command_timeout for 4 seconds.

---

But when I run the application, the command takes something about 8-12 seconds before it times out.

---

I also specified connection timeout in MySQL connection string, but with no luck

> default command timeout=4

It works for MsSqll and Oracle well, but for MySQL not.

Is there any way how to specify the timeout?

I found the issue there https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?38,634568,634568 but with no answer.

#### Edit

Code Sample

```
...         
DataTable outputNodes = new DataTable();
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 4;
sw.Start();
var a = cmd.ExecuteReader();
sw.Stop();
ex_time = sw.Elapsed;
sw.Reset();
outputNodes.Load(a);
CloseConnection();
...
```

Comment: MySQL Connector version?

Comment: You can also use something like `MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandTimeout = 4;`

Comment: @Hackerman MySQL Connector version 6.9.9.0

Comment: @Hackerman  I also specified cmd.CommandTimeout = 4. Result still same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a bug in Connector/NET. I've run into a number of bugs with `CommandTimeout`, e.g., [bug 88124](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=88124), [bug 87307](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=87307). I thought I even remembered filing a bug report about `MySqlCommand` taking 2× `CommandTimeout` before it actually timed out (which sounds like your situation), but I can't find it now (if I actually did file it).

If you have a consistent repro, I'd suggest filing a bug at [bugs.mysql.com](https://bugs.mysql.com/).

And if you have the flexibility to change drivers, try [MySqlConnector](https://github.com/mysql-net/MySqlConnector), which has a much more robust `CommandTimeout` implementation.

Comment: I found some of the bug reports too but from 2015. I thought it might be resolved now. Thanks for the information.